# Array conversion manipulation and formatting

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following array:

```
[
    {
        "level": "level3",
        "category": "car"
    },
    {
        "level": "level1",
        "category": "bike"
    },
    {
        "level": "level2",
        "category": "car"
    },
    {
        "level": "level5",
        "category": "bike"
    }
]
```

I need to convert this to the following object:

```
{
    car: ["level3", "level2"],
    bike: ["level1", "level5"],
}
```

What would be the best way to achieve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Give us your starting point and we'll help debug from there.

Comment: The "best way" is debatable. One option is [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: There's a mistake in the order of your example output. I suspect that `"level1"` ought to come before "`level5"`

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve what you want with many approaches:

### `for...of` approach

```js
const data = [ { "level": "level3", "category": "car" }, { "level": "level1", "category": "bike" }, { "level": "level2", "category": "car" }, { "level": "level5", "category": "bike" } ];
const newObj = {};
for (const item of data) {
  const {level,category} = item;
  if (newObj[category]) {
    newObj[category].push(level);
  } else {
    newObj[category] = [level];
  }
}
console.log(newObj);
```

### `reduce` approach

```js
const data = [ { "level": "level3", "category": "car" }, { "level": "level1", "category": "bike" }, { "level": "level2", "category": "car" }, { "level": "level5", "category": "bike" } ];
const newObj = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const { level, category } = item;
    acc[category] = acc[category] || [];
    acc[category].push(level);
    return acc;
}, {});
console.log(newObj);
```

The first approach is simple and understandable and the second is a more functional approach. But both approaches have a linear time complexity of O(n), choosing one of them is just a matter of personal preference and coding style.

Answer (score 1):

By using the function `Array.prototype.reduce`

```js
const array = [{        "level": "level3",        "category": "car"    },    { "level": "level1",        "category": "bike"    },    {        "level": "level2",        "category": "car"    },    {      "level": "level5",        "category": "bike"    }],
      result = array.reduce((a, {level, category}) => {
        (a[category] = a[category] || []).push(level);
        return a;
      }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```